# How to split the time from a timestamp from a nested array of result?

Tags: php, arrays

I have been doing a project in php and i get a nested array from where i have to extract the values.
Here from this array i have to get only the time from the timestamp i.e from [ArrTime] and [DepTIme]

```
[Segment] => stdClass Object
  (
    [WSSegment] => stdClass Object
      (

        [DepTIme] => 2014-12-10T15:40:00
        [ArrTime] => 2014-12-10T18:25:00
        [ETicketEligible] => 1
        [OperatingCarrier] => HW
      ) 

  )
```

I have being trying to apply the implode function on the timestamp but it is not working for me .

Comment: Those are actually nested objects.

Comment: `$dep = new DateTime($obj->Segment->WSSegment->DepTIme);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$DeptTime = date('H:i:s',strtotime($yourObject->Segment->WSSegment->DepTIme));
$ArrTime = date('H:i:s',strtotime($yourObject->Segment->WSSegment->ArrTime));
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to retrieve it in php

```
<?php
$str = '2014-12-10T15:40:00';
function getOnlyTime($str = '') {
  $time = '';
  if (empty($str)) {
    return $time;
  }
  return substr($str, 11);
}
echo getOnlyTime($yourObject->Segment->WSSegment->DepTIme);
echo getOnlyTime($yourObject->Segment->WSSegment->ArrTime);
?>
```

Live Example:

http://3v4l.org/1qChm

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the nested objects and see if the format matches a date. If it does, make an array of the matched elements. You could choose to index the array according to the index where it came from (if that matters later on in your code;

```
// Starts at "Segment"
foreach ($array as $segment => $item)
{
    // Loops through the values of"WSSegment"
    foreach ($item as $part => $value)
    {
        // Checks if the value is a valid date, might need to check type; $value must be a string
        if ($date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $value))
        {
            // Dump to an array.
            $dates[$part][] = $date;
        }
    }
}
$dates is now an array containing all valid dates in \DateTime format.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that I recommend for several reasons.  It saves one from having to manually extract the data by using `substr()` or `explode()`. The code uses two foreach loops to 'drill down to the desired items, namely the departure and arrival date-time data. If any of the names of the nested objects  were to change, the code will still run since it makes use of variables in referring to those entities. Using a DateTime object's format property provides a handy way to access just the time information and you can easily exclude the seconds as the following example illustrates:

```
   <?php
   /** 
     * getTime()
     * @param $str - date/time string
     * returns time in hours and minutes
   **/
   function getTime( $str ){
       $format = "H:i"; // Hours:Minutes
       $timeObj = new DateTime( $str );
       return $timeObj->format( $format );
   }

   foreach( $obj as $nested ) {
        foreach( $nested as $n ){
            echo 'DEP - ',getTime( $n->DepTime ),"\n";
            echo 'ARV - ',getTime( $n->ArrTime ),"\n";
        }

   }
```

See http://3v4l.org/IdQN1